# C#: VB.NET: How to extract value from this jagged string array

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

```
Dim strTest(recordSet.Count)() As String

While index < recordSet.Count
   strTest(index)(recordset.item(index).getvalue(0).tostring,
                  recordset.item(index).getvalue(0).tostring,
                  recordset.item(index).getvalue(0).tostring)
   index +=1
End While
```

Then once the array i populated above, i need to find the if another variable is contained in the second dimension of the second paren contains the value of my variable like this.

```
if strTest.Contains(someVariable) then
   extract the index and get the other two values in the array
end if
```

so basically is how do i perform the second block of code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For Each set As String() in strtest
   If set(1).Equals(someVariable) Then
     'Get set(0) and set(2)
   End If
Next
```

Loop through the array pulling the items as an array and check the middle item. I think that's what your question was saying.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use strTest.IndexOf()?